# How to get an inner view item?

Tags: java, android

I am using a view item called "FlingView"
this one has a content view called "item.xml" while my main activity uses main.xml.
How can I get an item (textview) inside item.xml while being in ActivityMain.java which sets the contentView to main.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your item.xml is a part of your main.xml then you can find your text view using its id like this,

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
```

else, then you can inflate it in your code as a view and find your text view using its id like this,

```
View item = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item, null);

TextView textView = item.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
```